# "Type mismatch error" with VLookup

Tags: excel, vba, variant, mismatch

I get a type mismatch error for the line `If first_unit = "N/A" Then`. I'm trying to change the text of a drop down menu (B26:C26) dependent on the selection in another drop down menu (B10). For the following code:

```
Dim check_change As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo 0


If check_change = False Then

If Target.Address = Range("B10").Address Then
    Dim first_unit As Variant
    Dim second_unit As Variant
    Dim third_unit As Variant

    check_change = True
    first_unit = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B10:E10"), Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 5, False)
    second_unit = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B10:E10"), Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 6, False)
    third_unit = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B10:E10"), Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 7, False)

    Range("D5").Value = first_unit
    Range("E5").Value = second_unit
    Range("F5").Value = third_unit

    If first_unit = "N/A" Then
        Range("B26:C26").Value = "Certified"
    End If

    check_change = False
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B19")) Is Nothing Then
    check_change = True
    Call ft_to_m(Range("D19"), Range("B19"))
    check_change = False
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D19")) Is Nothing Then
    check_change = True
    Call m_to_ft(Range("D19"), Range("B19"))
    check_change = False
    Exit Sub
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: **N/A** or **#N/A** ???

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177709/why-doesnt-iserror-work-with-a-vlookup-statement-in-excel-vba; note the difference between `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup()` and `Application.VLookup()`

Answer (score 0):

First argument in Vlookup is a lookup value,  not Range, I think it is "B10" not Range("B10:E10")

You need to use Error Handling for Vlookup
' Enable error handling by 'On Error Resume Next' instead of on error Goto 0

```
Sub test1()
On Error Resume Next 

    first_unit = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B10").value, Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 5, False)
        'first_unit = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B10:E10"), Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 5, False )

    If IsError(first_unit) = False Then
    ' Example
    first_unit = "N/A"

    Else

    first_unit = "Otherwise"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. The first argument is the lookup value, not a range. Excel converts the cell to a value in the function. So to be clear you should use `Range("B10").Value` as the first argument. And you're right, you can't use a multi cell range for that.

Comment: @D_bester Why you down vote my answer? even after i provide proper review of yourcode?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.VLookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup()` so that it doesn't raise an error if the lookup fails. Then you can check `IsError()` to determine whether you have a valid result or an error. In Excel it shows #N/A error if the value is not found in the lookup table. Using `IsError()` will catch the error.

Also the first argument is the lookup value, not a range. Excel converts the cell to a value in the function. So to be clear you should use `Range("B10").Value` as the first argument. And you can't use a multi cell range for that.

```
first_unit = Application.VLookup(Range("B10").Value, Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 5, False)
second_unit = Application.VLookup(Range("C10").Value, Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 6, False)
third_unit = Application.VLookup(Range("D10").Value, Sheet3.Range("Jurisdictions_table"), 7, False)

If Not IsError(first_unit) Then Range("D5").Value = first_unit
If Not IsError(second_unit) Then Range("E5").Value = second_unit
If Not IsError(third_unit) Then Range("F5").Value = third_unit

If IsError(first_unit) Then
    Range("B26:C26").Value = "Certified"
End If
```

[CPearson: Error Handling With Worksheet Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx)

Comment: If this answer helps you please accept it by checking the checkmark on the left. If it doesn't work, let me know.